# VB Webclient "The underlying connection was closed"

Tags: vb.net, webclient

When I try to DownloadString from a website I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrUZp.jpg). This error has never come up and has worked all of the time, I have no changed this line of code for at least a month now but for some reason it is creating an error.

Just a bit of information that may be helpful: The variable "Word" is what every the user inputs, I made sure to input a word that exists for example "taberu" (a Japanese word) which then concatenates to "https://jisho.org/search/taberu", this should work because [the page exists](https://jisho.org/search/taberu). (I also checked in the 'autos' window and I am definitely right about the concatenation.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

EDIT; In short, this is my code:

```
Dim Word As String = Console.Readline
Dim WordURL As String = "https://jisho.org/search/" & Word
Dim Client As New WebClient
Client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

Dim HTML As String
HTML = Client.DownloadString(New Uri(WordURL)) 'this is the line that causes the error
```

Comment: Seems to compile and run fine in VS 2017.  The HTML string seems to populate properly.  Do you get that error every time you run it?

Comment: I found the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APPARENTLY, adding the following line of code makes it work

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Tls11 also works

I have no idea why but it fixed my issue. [Source](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-fix-the-error-authentication-failed-because-the-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream/)

Comment: You should use an [up to date version of .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) if you can and avoid needing to use this fix.

Comment: Wow! I remember I changed the version and forgot that I did so! Thank you!